# How does react-native-scripts start work?

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

I am learning `react-native` with https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app. It has an interesting module: `react-native-scripts`.

Can someone explain me how `react-native-scripts start` work?

Looks like it mimics the `expo` module, or is a wrapper for `expo`, so I am curious why the developers have chosen to do that instead of just using `expo` directly.

I like the way it can load an `expo` server without making you get an account and use tunneling, how is it doing that?

Comment: You're getting in way too deep. I have been doing RN for a year and never got that deep. That deep stuff was purposefully abstracted away from you so you don't have to worry about it.